# What's the orrect configuration of a T connector for track lighting?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I just put up a bit of track for a system and used a mix of manufacturers (Lithonia, Satco and Hampton Bay) — all of the track is the H style. Adding a small piece of track, I put one head on and (using a Maestro dimmer) it worked. When I added a T connector, it stopped working. I connected one side of the straight end (the top stroke of the T) to a power feed and then an 8' track to the side that's a right angle to that. I'm sure I got the ground side where it should be but - nothing.  I'm wondering if the power is meant to b connected only to the middle connector and not one of the sides?
---Rob

Comment: It may be as simple as your mix-n-match system just won't work due to incompatibilities in the _electrical_ connections, not just the physical ones.

Comment: I am not aware of a NEMA standard for track lighting or any standard other than safety so that may be a way to back up what freeman is saying.